# How to show a loading circle on slack app home while my app is retrieving data?

Tags: slack, slack-api

The `view.publish` API can be used to provide an interactive interface to the user.

However, there is a delay of several seconds between the time my app receives the `app_home_opened` event and the time it calls the `view.publish` API, because my app should retrieve data. During this time, I would like to display a loading circle in App Home.

There is no mention of how to display it in the Slack API documentation. Apps like Google Calendar do this, so this should not be impossible.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Hey kintsiw, as I checked last time the Google Calendar slack app for the loading circle. It appears due to the delay in real-time data retrieval/refresh from google calendar server. As I build enterprise slack apps, this happens when you reload the page and publishing it after every update/action with app running on medium to high latency servers. As a solution to retrieving your data, you can use the view.update API to update in page or view.publish to publish app home every time when user opens the slack app

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't know that we could use `view.update` API to update App Home (I thought all we could do for App Home was `view.publish` API).
After every action such as clicking a button, a loading circle will appear near the button, you know. But I want to present a gray-out that covers the entire App Home and a loading circle on it, as shown in the attached image, by notifying Slack by some API and/or its parameters that my app is retrieving data. https://imgur.com/a/UgWGtYh

Comment: You can use multiple view.publish too. First viw.publish to show loading screen(before it actually loads data). And second view.publish to show actual data

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Calling `view.publish` twice seems to be a very good idea. So, in the first call, how can we notify Slack that the app will be retrieving data, to show a loading screen?